Prove if omitted variable is independent it does not affect coefficient estimate
Suppose I have two linear models (not classical):
$$Y = X\beta^* + Z\gamma^* + \epsilon^*$$
and $$Y = X\beta + \epsilon$$
I want to show that $X$ and $Z$ being independent $\implies$ $\beta^* = \beta$.
Finding the conditional expectation of the first model yields $E[Y|X] = X\beta^* + E[Z]\gamma^*$ then for the second model we have $E[Y|X] = X \beta$. Since I don't have any classical assumptions of normality of the residuals etc. I cannot use OLS.
I know intuitively it makes sense, as since $Z$ provides no information on $X$ the presence of it should not influence the true value of the coefficient vector $\beta^*$ and thus should be identical to the misspecified vector $\beta$.
Any hints first?
